# Install marketplace on Eclipse ide for java ee developers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

How do I install marketplace on Eclipse ide for java ee developers? I'm using Eclipse Platform v3.3.2. I want marketplace to install Glassfish, Subversion and other tools.

Comment: If you downloaded Eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ , you can find the marketplace in your Eclipse.

Comment: Oh wow how silly, but thank you! Our TA posted a link from the Europa site and it was completely outdated. Thank you, you just saved me so much time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Marketplace Download page](http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/archive.php), you will see that the first version supported is Helios, Eclipse 3.6. So I don't think that the Marketplace could work with your installation Europe, Eclipse 3.3.2. You have to hunt for all the things you need in an older version, at least for Subversion you should find it.

The better option would be to update at least to Eclipse 3.7.